# QEMU serial std output diverges on archlinux guest

Tags: serial-port, qemu, archlinux

I'm trying to bootstrap some installation automation of a freshly downloaded ISO in QEMU. I create a clean img to install to and kick off QEMU like this:

```sh
$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 out/main.img 15G
$ qemu-system-x86_64
  -m 8G \
  -serial stdio \
  -cdrom out/linux.iso \
  -drive file=out/main.img,if=virtio \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
  -device e1000,netdev=net0
```

and I can see Arch boot up. At first both the display and the terminal are in sync, but they soon diverge after this the GRUB boot up screen.

[image: qemu display/terminal both on grub]
[image: qemu display has active session while terminal does not]

I'm not sure what piece I'm missing to get this to work. I've seen some people suggest adding `-append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0"` to your QEMU arguments, but (from what I can tell) while it requires you to extract the kernel and the initram from the ISO (which should be easy enough as mounting and copy/pasting the correct files) but it also expects you to already have an installed system on `/dev/sda` (which is what I'm trying to bootstrap).

At this point I don't know what to search for next, how do I get the full terminal session in my current terminal and not just in my display?

Comment: This is an archlinux question more than a QEMU question, I think -- you might want to add some relevant tags if you know them. You need to find out how to get the archlinux installer to run on the serial port (which will be the same way you would do that if you're running the installer on real hardware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it was as [@Peter Maydell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069805/qemu-serial-std-output-diverges-on-archlinux-guest?noredirect=1#comment122077879_69069805) commented; this is not a QEMU question. QEMU was doing exactly what it was supposed to do, but Arch had to be told to utilize the serial console as its primary means of communication.

Two samples of how this can be done

###### bash via console

```sh
pipe_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
mkfifo "${pipe_dir}/pipe.in" "${pipe_dir}/pipe.out"
function cleanup {
    rm -rfv "${pipe_dir}"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 8G \
  -display none \
  -serial stdio \
  -drive file=./out/linux.iso,index=0,media=cdrom \
  -drive file=./out/main.img,if=virtio &

sleep 2s
printf "\t" > "${pipe_dir}/pipe.in"
sleep 2s
printf " console=ttyS0,115200" > "${pipe_dir}/pipe.in"
sleep 2s
echo  > "${pipe_dir}/pipe.in"

# Whatever other interactions you want go here...

wait
```

###### expect via console

```
set timeout -1
spawn qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 8G \
  -display none \
  -serial stdio \
  -drive file=./out/linux.iso,index=0,media=cdrom \
  -drive file=./out/main.img,if=virtio

sleep 1
send \t
sleep 1
send " console=ttyS0,115200"
sleep 1
send \n
```

In theory this should be fine, but in practice I still had difficulty interacting with the console and sending characters over to login correctly. I'm sure there is probably more user-error on my part than not.

A better solution (again contextual to Arch and not QEMU specifically) was to use a cloud-init script that included my SSH public key. Interactions with the VM were stable, reliable, and easily reproducible.

###### bash with cloud-init/ssh

```sh
$ touch ./out/meta-data
$ cat > ./out/user-data <<EOF
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: root
    ssh_authorized_keys:
        - $(cat ${HOME}/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub)
EOF
$ xorriso -as genisoimage -output ./out/cloud-init.iso \
    -volid CIDATA -joliet -rock ./out/meta-data ./out/user-data
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 8G \
    -drive file=./out/linux.iso,index=0,media=cdrom \
    -drive file=./out/cloud-init.iso,index=1,media=cdrom \
    -drive file=./out/main.img,if=virtio \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 \
    -net nic &

$ function qemu-ssh {
    ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" -p 10022 root@localhost ${@}
  }

$ printf 'Waiting for SSH to go live (this will take a while)...'
$ until qemu-ssh exit; do
    printf '.'
  done

# This convenience function starts an interactive
# session when supplied with no additional arguments
# but your automation can go here
$ qemu-ssh
```